# Can I use comments on a question to link to my answer on that question when current answers are misleading or out of date?

Tags: discussion, comments

Today I answered an old question which asks something like:

Is it possible to do xyz with CSS?

Now when the question was asked - it wasn't possible, and all the current answers basically say that you can't do it.

I then added an answer to show that today using newer CSS features - it is possible.

I then noticed that there are about 12 answers there, and chances are that not many people will see the answer (due to the amount of scrolling necessary to get there) - so I added a comment on the question saying that it's possible - linking to my answer.

Is this practice ok?

Should I delete that comment? or

Write a different comment mentioning the new css technology (without the link to my post) or

Leave it as is?

Comment: The accepted answer has many votes and is answered by an extremely well known and authoritative user,... So I think most people would just accept his answer (which was of course correct at the time of posting)

Comment: I updated the question title to reflect the context of the question

Comment: Just found this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202109/flagging-look-at-my-answer-pls-comments/202111#202111 - from the the answer there - it would seem that in this context it would be ok to leave a descriptive comment with a link to my answer.

Comment: @davidism - they are actually misleading because they are out of date and say that it can't be done when it can. (even though like I said before they were perfectly correct when they posted them)

Comment: I'd prefer not to tamper with other people's answers. In any case I think that the post I linked to suffices to justify linking to my answer in this case. But if you can show me a different authoritative post which clearly refutes that, I'll happily follow that advice. After all, I want to do the right thing - that's why I asked the question in the first place :)

Comment: @Danield it's perfectly fine to point out potential shortcomings in another answer with a comment.  If that comment links to your answer to address that problem, that's helpful.  Just don't spam this comment.

Comment: It feels weird leaving a comment on someone else's answer (like the accepted one) after I've already added my own answer. Anyway, being that there are like 5 other answers that say "it can't be done" - leaving a comment on the question itself seems more appropriate than leaving a comment on particular answers. Maybe I'll leave this question open for a bit - I might be lucky and a moderator might post an answer here.

Answer (score 6):

I always read comments on accepted answers because sometimes you get context there that you don't get in the answer itself. Regardless of whether or not comments like that *should* be incorporated into the answer, the fact of the matter is they frequently aren't.

In this case, my recommendation is you put a comment on the accepted answer indicating that, while it was correct at the time, it is now no longer so as of (date). If I were reading that answer, I would see that comment and know that I need to keep looking because my solution is still out there.

The link to the answer within the question page itself is probably a bit much. If I were really looking for the answer I would look at what everyone that answered had to say. If I were just browsing from curiosity and didn't care what the final answer is then it wouldn't matter anyway.